# Python Regex - Capturing Groups of Repeating Patterns

Tags: python, regex

I have a log file that I am trying to parse. Example of log file is below:

> Oct 23 13:03:03.714012 prod1_xyz(RSVV)[201]: #msgtype=EVENT #server=Web/Dev@server1web #func=LKZ_WriteData ( line 2992 ) #rc=0 #msgid=XYZ0064 #reqid=0 #msg=Web Activity end (section 200, # SysD 1, Files 222, Bytes 343422089928, Errors 0, Aborted Files 0, Busy Files 0)

I want to pull out all the text that start with a hash, and have a key and value. For example, #msgtype=EVENT.  Any text that has a hash only, and no "=" sign, will be treated as a value.

So in the above log entry, I want a list that looks like this

```
#msgtype=EVENT
#server=Web/Dev@server1web
#func=LKZ_WriteData ( line 2992 ) 
#rc=0
#msgid=XYZ0064 
#reqid=0
#msg=Web Activity end (section 200, # SysD 1, Files 222, Bytes 343422089928, Errors 0, Aborted Files 0, Busy Files 0) (Notice the hash present in the middle of the text)
```

I have tried the Python regex findall option, but I am not able to capture all data.

For example:

```
str='Oct 23 13:03:03.714012 prod1_xyz(RSVV)[201]: #msgtype=EVENT #server=Web/Dev@server1web #func=LKZ_WriteData ( line 2992 ) #rc=0 #msgid=XYZ0064 #reqid=0 #msg=Web Activity end (section 200, # SysD 1, Files 222, Bytes 343422089928, Errors 0, Aborted Files 0, Busy Files 0)'

z = re.findall("(#.+?=.+?)(:?#|$)",str)
print(z)
```

Output:

```
[('#msgtype=EVENT ', '#'), ('#func=LKZ_WriteData ( line 2992 ) ', '#'), ('#msgid=XYZ0064 ', '#'), ('#msg=Web Activity end (section 200, ', '#')]
```

Comment: `re.findall(r'#[^\s=]+=.*?(?=\s*#[^\s=]+=|$)', text)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Kg0nDU/1)

Answer (score 1):

The `(:?#|$)` is a *capturing* group that matches an optional `:` and then `#`, or end of string. Since `re.findall` returns all captured substrings the result is a list of tuples.

You need

```
re.findall(r'#[^\s=]+=.*?(?=\s*#[^\s=]+=|$)', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Kg0nDU/1)

**Regex details**

- `#[^\s=]+` - `#` and then any 1+ chars other than whitespace and `=`
- `=` - a `=` char
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?=\s*#[^\s=]+=|$)` - up to (and excluding) 0+ whitespaces, `#`, 1+ chars other than whitespace and `=` and then `=` or up the end of string.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

s = "Oct 23 13:03:03.714012 prod1_xyz(RSVV)[201]: #msgtype=EVENT #server=Web/Dev@server1web #func=LKZ_WriteData ( line 2992 ) #rc=0 #msgid=XYZ0064 #reqid=0 #msg=Web Activity end (section 200, # SysD 1, Files 222, Bytes 343422089928, Errors 0, Aborted Files 0, Busy Files 0)"

a = re.findall('#(?=[a-zA-Z]+=).+?=.*?(?= #[a-zA-Z]+=|$)', s)

result = [item.split('=') for item in a]

print(result)
```

Gives:

```
[['#msgtype', 'EVENT'], ['#server', 'Web/Dev@server1web'], ['#func', 'LKZ_WriteData ( line 2992 )'], ['#rc', '0'], ['#msgid', 'XYZ0064'], ['#reqid', '0'], ['#msg', 'Web Activity end (section 200, # SysD 1, Files 222, Bytes 343422089928, Errors 0, Aborted Files 0, Busy Files 0)']]
```